# Extending the Mathematica highlighter to gist and github

Tags: discussion

I hope this is not too off topic, but does somebody know, how hard it would be to extend the current [Mathematica syntax highlighter](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118/syntax-highlighter-problem-reports-please-test) to work on [gists](https://gist.github.com/) and [github](https://github.com/) in general?

Or perhaps we should just contact github and ask them to add yet another language syntax highlighter? They have Matlab, so why not Mathematica:)

Answer (score 4):

GitHub uses a different syntax highlighting engine than StackExchange: [pygments](http://pygments.org/), so porting the one we use here ([prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)-based) is probably not trivial.  In their [FAQ](http://help.github.com/common-issues-and-questions/) they mention that they're open to adding new languages if people are willing to contribute them to the pygments project.

Comment: Aha, I see the issue is already [open](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issue/710/mathematica-highlighting) in the pygments repository. But of course with minor priority.

Comment: @Ajasja Are you planning to start work on this?  That'd be excellent!

Comment: Short answer: No. 
Long answer: Sorry, never used python much. But the main problem is that I have to finish my PHD very soon, so I can't make any additional commitments right now:)

Comment: Perhaps we could start a question with a good bounty on the main site?

Comment: @Ajasja Probably not on main if it's in python...

Comment: @R.M Well, on the main site it would attract the most attention... Posting directly on stackoverflow (like the original [js question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957682/can-prettify-js-be-extended-to-support-mathematica/8959323#8959323) is another option)

Comment: @Ajasja Well, python is off-topic for mma.se, isn't it? ;) Anyway, I think that JS question just got lucky... technically, it's a pure "gimme the codez, I haz bounty!" question that went unnoticed :) You're welcome to try on [so], but my hunch says _both_ questions will get closed... (not that it matters if the second gets closed now). Don't let me stop you though!

Comment: @R.M I *might* give it a shot if I have time.  I guess this meta post should be okay to coordinate...

Comment: @R.M Of course it's that kind of question. But mma.se would be much worse if there were no syntax highlighting, so sometimes it's good to turn a blind eye:)